# Magento extension subfolder change

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to localize an extension i bought from Magento store.

```
http://www.sitename.com/extname/ to http://www.sitename.com/myext
```

I have changed the config.xml file to do this change.

```
<routers>
        <extname>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Magestore_extname</module>
                <frontName>myext</frontName>
            </args>
        </extname>
</routers>
```

But the url doesn't change. Any thoughts? I am new to Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Clear cache`/var/` by deleting or changing the folder name from `cache` to a different name